# indexOfMaxInRange return wrong number?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have this method that should return the index of an array with the highest value ::

```js
public static int indexOfMaxInRange(int[] a, int lowIndex, int highIndex){
        if((highIndex - lowIndex) == 0){
            return highIndex;
        }else if(a[lowIndex] >= a[highIndex]){
            return maxInRange(a, lowIndex, highIndex - 1);
        }else{
            return maxInRange(a, lowIndex + 1, highIndex);
        }  
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[5];
        a[0] = 4;
        a[1] = 3;
        a[2] = 6;
        a[3] = 4;
        a[4] = 2;
        System.out.println(indexOfMaxInRange(a, 0, a.length - 1));
    }
```

when i tried to run it with that array it returns 6 and not 2 why??? 
thanks in advance,

Comment: Methods is called `indexOfMaxInRange`, but it returns value from `maxInRange`

Comment: show `maxInRange` method

Comment: That should be recursive call to `indexOfMaxInRange`, that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int indexOfMaxInRange(int[] a, int lowIndex, int highIndex){
    if((highIndex - lowIndex) == 0){
        return highIndex;
    }else if(a[lowIndex] >= a[highIndex]){
        //Changed to recursive call
        return indexOfMaxInRange(a, lowIndex, highIndex - 1);
    }else{
        //Changed to recursive call
        return indexOfMaxInRange(a, lowIndex + 1, highIndex);
    }  
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[5];
    a[0] = 4;
    a[1] = 3;
    a[2] = 6;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 2;
    System.out.println(indexOfMaxInRange(a, 0, a.length - 1));
}
```

This snippet with recursive calls works perfectly.

Comment: I think this was what the OP was trying to do, might just be a Typo from his part so you might need to highlight the correction ;) I missed it the first time I read his code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use recursive change **`maxInRange` to `indexOfMaxInRange`** it will work fine.

And one more way,use a for loop instead of recursive.Check for max value and keep track of index and return

```
  public static int indexOfMaxInRange(int[] a, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {
        int maxIndex = 0;
        int maxVal = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(maxVal < a[i]){
                maxVal = a[i];
                maxIndex=i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
```

Comment: I would say `Recursive is funnier` ;)